# Caching issues relating to HTTP headers, Chrome, WSGI

Tags: python, caching, google-chrome, webserver, wsgi

I'm trying to cache some static files. I am using the following HTTP headers:

```
Date            Sat, 08 Oct 2011 19:34:30 GMT
Content-Length  770
Last-Modified   Wed, 05 Oct 2011 05:45:29 GMT
Server          WSGIServer/0.1 Python/2.7.1+
Content-Type    text/css
Cache-Control   public, max-age=3153600
Expires         Sun, 07 Oct 2012 19:34:30 GMT
```

However, when I access the file via Chrome while debugging into the WSGI server, the server still is processing this file.

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This does look very similar to a question that I just asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9176874/webkit-not-caching-when-both-max-age-and-last-modified-headers-are-provide). I seem to be getting an interaction between the Last-Modified and max-age headers. If the Last-Modified header is specified then max-age is ignored.